# When an Activity goes into the background after onStop(), does it lose its member variable values?

Tags: android, android-activity

When an Activity goes into the background after another Activity covers it completely and after onStop() is invoked, 
does it lose its member variable values?

If it is brought back into the foreground, will the member variables be in their initial declarative state with default values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not immediately, but once it's stopped it can be removed from memory at any time and then it will lose its state.

If you need to preserve state, use the onSaveIntanceState callback to store your state and restore it in onCreate().

Answer (score 0):

It will not unless and until you destroy the activity.